# database design for some of the master data having factual information

Tags: sql-server, database-design, data-modeling

How to do the DB design for the master table having factual information only for few of the rows.
Say for e.g. we have the state_province table which lists all the states.
The requirement from UI is,

1. they need only those list of states, which are territories??
2. THey can update any of these territories with surcharge info. During display they should only see those territories for which it got updated, the option will be there to add new ones.

Below approaches, I have in mind.

- In the state_province table, have the territory_flag column to serve
  the 1st reqmt.
- add the surcharge_flag and surcharge_amt in the same state_province
  table, the  surcharge_flag will help to indicate if the surcharge was
  updated for that territory.

The 2nd approach was thinking that have a separate table to capture the surcharge info. for the updated territories.

Just thinking that the 1st approach will reduce the tables, as we already have many tables in our DB. Let me know the preferred approach for reasons.

Comment: There is nowhere near enough information here to offer any solid advice on designing your database. One thing to keep in mind is that it is not the job of the design to keep tables to a minimum. Don't get stuck in the mindset that fewer tables is always the best approach.

Comment: In the surcharge example, a second table would be useful if you need to keep a history of the changes and see what the previous values where, who previously updated it etc. If it's merely sufficient to capture the fact it was changed (and perhaps the last time it was changed and who changed it) then you should be able to do that within the province table. But yeah like Sean said, minimising the number of tables should not be a design goal, creating a correctly normalised structure which meets the requirements should be the goal

Comment: As we are not maintaining the history, will go with the surcharge field added to state_Province table itself. But in the UI how they will come to know which territories are updated  , shall we go with one more surcharge_flag field in the same table to identify if the surcharge was really updated. This is for them to actually display in the UI,  the territories that were updated with surcharge info. Let me know if you guys know any better approach.

Comment: What does Requirement 2 actually mean? It seems like you're trying to include too many workflow steps here without proper explanation. In Req. 1, you say the UI only wants to see states that are also territories, but then in Req. 2 you state the UI only wants to display territories that have had the surcharge info updated. This seems like a "chicken & egg" problem.

Comment: "how they will come to know which territories are updated". Well if you store the date it was last updated, then you can simply check whether that field is populated, or is null. That'll tell you which ones were updated. You can also sort by date if you want to see which ones changed recently. I don't think you really need a separate flag field.